# django many to many uml confusing

Tags: django, django-models, uml, class-diagram

In my project i have a many to many relation. as django can handle a many to many relationship, i did like that:

```
class Groups (models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        groups_to_users=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='handler')
```

I have to make umls diagrams, so unless i'm wrong django create the relation table between the both. for the database i did explicitely apear this one.
but in the class diagram how can i handle that ? can class have many to many in uml ?
I guess no, so humm ????   :)

Answer (score 1):

What django does is an implementation detail. This is valid UML:

[image]

Comment: so in the class diagram i will do like that but in the uml database diagram i have to put the join table between even if django handle that without creating it ?

Comment: Django should create it. Did you forget to `syncdb`?